# web framework that will reduce number of lines of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, django, jsp

which framework helps in reducing the number of lines of code needed to create a web app?

ruby on rails?
php?
asp.net mvc?
jsp/servlet?
django/python?

I just don't like typing a lot of code especially if it's boilerplate.  If I can write 10 lines of code versus 100 to get the same results, I think most people would prefer 10...right?  So, tell me which web framework will acheive this goal.

Comment: PHP isn't a framework, and neither is JSP/servlet, and neither is python.

The only frameworks you mention are ruby on rails and django.

Comment: My simplier PHP view class, with forms, validation, models process: 2200 Lines. A lot. I did the same with django: 40 Lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can answer this question yourself with this way: **Do the get started project**.

In my case was: `django/python`, why?, see the [get started project](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01), will take a 1 or 2 hours to understand/develop/deploy, and not python knowledge required, just a hyperactive open mind.

Comment: How could anybody consider the getting started project represents a fair example of the strengths of a web framework?

Comment: @jfar comeeon!, if you do a framework the minimal thing that you have to do for sharing it to the world is a "getting started project" for show the benefits, for compete, django starting project shows: "make a CRUD with only 2 lines of code". you have to read more man. my anwer wasnt "django is the best framework" for get a bad calification, was: django cuz if you make the starting project then..etc etc.

Comment: 99.99% of the apps in the world aren't 1-2 hour blog apps and the "etc, etc" part after the contrite blog use case is where these "frameworks" fall apart.  Would you buy a car on the basis on how well it drove 10 feet?  There is no little different between a Bugatti and a Yugo in the first 10 feet.

Comment: I can make a framework that you can use to build a blog with 1 line of code.

Answer (score 3):

All of them.

I wouldn't use "Shortest program" as a guiding factor in selecting one though.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what backend and DB you are using to support your web app.

I mean, if you are consuming .Net web services then I think asp.net (and visual studio) would be the best match to generate all code behind classes to consume the data strongly typed. Other backend/db maybe make you choose a totally different path.

Answer (score 0):

For a complex application: [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st). None of the others comes close. Especially when you run it on a OODB like Gemstone: [Glass](http://glass.gemstone.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is completely circumstantial; certain frameworks will require less lines of code for specific purposes. Perhaps if you can give the StackOverflow readers an idea of the kind of task you wish to accomplish, they can point you in the direction of the framework that is most likely to accomplish the task in fewest lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

SilverStripe requires almost no lines and no understanding of PHP. It comes with the UI, Auth, and everything you need to get started.

http://silverstripe.org/

http://www.slideshare.net/chillu/modeladmin-in-silverstripe-23

http://doc.silverstripe.com/doku.php?id=modeladmin